# Redirect from asp.net web api post action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm very new to ASP.NET 4.0 Web API. Can we redirect to another URL at the end of the POST action?, something like ... `Response.Redirect(url)`

Actually I upload file from a MVC application (say `www.abcmvc.com`) through Web API (say `www.abcwebapi.com/upload`)

Here `upload` is the POST action. I post a multi-part form to Web API upload controller's post action. After uploading I would like to redirect back to `www.abcmvc.com`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Sure:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    // ... do the job

    // now redirect
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.abcmvc.com");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Using this Redirect technique solved the "object moved to" WebAPI page I was getting with other redirect techniques.  Also for Redirect temporary instead of permanent you can use `HttpStatusCode.Redirect` (302) or `.RedirectMethod` (303)

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, this works.  Why is it that when I use  HttpStatusCode.Redirect instead, my client receives a 401 response?

Answer (score 28):

Here is another way you can get to the root of your website without hard coding the url:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
string fullyQualifiedUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
response.Headers.Location = new Uri(fullyQualifiedUrl);
```

Note:
*Will only work if both your MVC website and WebApi are on the same URL*

Answer (score 17):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public RedirectResult Get()
    {
        return RedirectPermanent("https://www.google.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

**You can check this**

```
[Route("Report/MyReport")]
public IHttpActionResult GetReport()
{

   string url = "https://localhost:44305/Templates/ReportPage.html";

   System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(url);

   return Redirect(uri);
}
```

Comment: @dotnetguy Please stop suggesting the same edit. If you want, post the code you changed in a separate answer. There is no point in continuing to edit, the reviewers will turn each edit down.

Comment: Redirect get a string arg ,according microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8.1

Answer (score 2):

If you use ASP.NET Web API you can just use the following

```
app.MapGet("/", () => Results.Redirect("/swagger"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
[HttpGet]
public RedirectResult Get() {
  return new RedirectResult("https://example.com");
}
```