# Redirect to new url C# MVC with HttpResponse.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am struggling with the `HttpResponse.Redirect` method. I thought it would be included in `System.Web` but I am getting the

> The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context" error.

This is the entire controller:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class SmileyController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
            return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                Content = new StringContent("[]", new UTF8Encoding(), "application/json"),
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect from asp.net web api post action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549324/net-mvc-redirect-to-external-url

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get HttpResponse object for current request in Your action method using the following line:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response
```

and so You can write:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

Anyway, You use HttpResponseMessage, so the proper way to redirect would be like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
    // Your logic here before redirection

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Why isnt the HttpStatusCode.Redirect used?

Comment: @Martea `HttpStatusCode.Redirect` is a temporary redirect. `HttpStatusCode.Moved` indicates the redirect is permanent.

Answer (score 1):

In an MVC web application controller, Response isn't accessed in the same way as it would be from an aspx page. You need to access it through the current http context.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Headers.Location` property in your `HttpResponseMessage` instead.

Comment: He needs to also change the status code to 301 or 302 rather than 404.