# Redirecting to subdomain from WebAPI controller - CORS required?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors, http-redirect

Currently, my WebAPI controller does this:

```
var newUrl = _adminService.Foo(bar);
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, newUrl);
```

So the client receives a string, and then sets `window.location` with javascript.

This seems like a hacky way to redirect via WebAPI.  I found this post:

[Redirect from asp.net web api post action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action)

Which I've implemented:

```
var newUrl = _adminService.Foo(bar);
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
response.Headers.Location = new Uri(newUrl);
return response;
```

But now I get the following error in chrome (when navigating from localhost to the subdomain):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.localhost:3806/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3806' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Do I need to configure CORS for this?

Comment: Why would you want a service (WebApi) to force the client to do anything?

Comment: @Maess the user POSTs via webAPI and then gets redirected.  Same as a MVC controller.

Comment: Why not use an MVC controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to configure CORS for this?

Yes, you do need if your javascript is hosted on a different domain than your Web API.

Comment: I'm confused - I'm not using javascript with the new approach.  I'm redirecting via headers.  The original method was working, but the header redirect isn't.

Comment: You are not using javascript??? Where does `XMLHttpRequest` comes from in the error message then? This is AJAX.

Comment: I am using it but it shouldn't get hit when I return the `redirect` response, right?  I thought that as soon as the browser sees the '301' it would push to the specified URI...  but it looks like my `.fail` callback is getting hit from the origin page because of the redirect header.  Does your recommendation from the other post not work with cross-domain redirects?

Comment: In order to be able to even *hit* the server from an AJAX call, this remote server must support CORS. Otherwise the browser will simply emit the warning you are seeing. You seem to have redirected to some `http://test.localhost:3806/` but, whatever is listening at this address does not support CORS to `http://localhost:3806`. If you want to be able to access this `http://test.localhost:3806/` the script located there must send appropriate CORS headers.

Comment: Understood - (and thank you for the help) - I have enabled CORS and I no longer get the above error.   The controller returns a payload with contents set to the new page (subdomain), but the redirect in the browser never takes place.  The fail callback is hit on the origin page (localhost) instead.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Is it necessary to host web api and web client like angular on different domain or they can be hosted on same domain?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you have to use CORS but not all browser support it.

[here](http://caniuse.com/cors) there is a compatibility table and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) some Restrictions, Limitations and Workarounds for IE 8/9