# Redirecting from an API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to learn/expand my knowledge of .NET MVC/REST/API's and Web-sockets/SignalR. To do this I am implementing a chat app.

I have a typical MVC intro page that gets the users name and email address in a form and that data is submitted to a RESTFul API where the new user is added to the database.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/api/GroopsAPIUsers" method="POST">
```

Inside of the controller for that page(?) I'm redirecting the user to a page where they can select which room they would like to enter.

```
public HttpResponseMessage  Post( GroopsUser userValue)
{
     userValue.ID =  Guid.NewGuid();
     bool results = groopsRepository.AddNewUser(userValue);
     //   return results;

     var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);

      //from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action

     string fullyQualifiedUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
     response.Headers.Location = new Uri (fullyQualifiedUrl + "/home/rooms/?userID=" + userValue.ID);

     return response;

}
```

But this doesn't feel right. It seems like the API should only be doing CRUD operations and shouldn't have anything to do with which page the user is redirected to.

Is this the wrong approach?
If so, can someone point me in the right direction?
(I'm not sure that I've used all of these terms correctly)

...gregory

Comment: I am new too in API. So far, I never do redirect thing in API to the real application. An Application Programming Interface (API) is a doorway into the programming model that exposed so you can enhance or extend some capability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can see why you don't think it feels right. Usually, you would design your Web API in such a way, that it is platform agnostic, so the only thing it cares about is the incoming HTTP requests, and operations based on those. When you redirect a request to another URL, you are designing around the web browser, thus constraining yourself to that one platform. Sometimes that's what you need, sometimes it isn't. 
(if it indeed *is* what you need, then you should probably stick to just regular Asp.NET MVC, and not Web Api)

Instead of what you have now, you could make your application more flexible by returning, for example, a 200 status code from your controller, after a successful operation. That way, it is up to the client-side application to decide what to do from there. (This is where you redirect, if your client-side application is browser-based.)

So how exactly do you achieve this with your browser application? You might already have guessed it, but the answer is Javascript. Instead of making a synchronous POST request to your API, via your form, you could make the request async, and then wait for the response from the server. Then you can take an appropriate action, based on what the response contains.

A quick example:

**Controller**

```
public HttpResponseMessage  Post(GroopsUser userValue)
{
     userValue.ID =  Guid.NewGuid();
     bool results = groopsRepository.AddNewUser(userValue);

     var response = Request.CreateResponse<GroopsUser>(HttpStatusCode.OK, userValue);

     return response;
}
```

**Form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="group-form" onsubmit="return addToGroup()" role="form" action="/api/GroopsAPIUsers" method="POST">
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
<script>
    function addToGroup()
    {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $('#group-form').attr('action'),
                data: $('#group-form').serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    window.location.replace('/home/rooms/?userID=' + data.ID);
                },
                error: function(){
                      alert('error handing here');
                }
            });
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

If anything is unclear, or if I'm mistaken about anything, please let me know!

Comment: Very cool. Thank you for taking the time to explain in such detail. It's really appreciated. Last night I pretty much ended up with the same result...although yours has more detail that I'll incorporate (httpstatus and using json in the response). Am I missing something, or does your controller only return the HttpStatus and not the userId? I ended up with ->  var response = Request.CreateResponse<GroopsRoom>(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, roomData);

Comment: I would upvote you, but apparently my rep isn't high enough yet. :)

Comment: @mertens3d, you're right, I forgot to send the user data along with the response. I'll update my answer. :)

Comment: @Tobias...oh yeah, I forgot to ask. It is acceptable to return data from a "POST", correct? (As opposed to doing a POST and then a GET)

Comment: @mertens3d Sure, in my experience, it is a common REST convention to return data from a POST. Use it to return any important details about the request.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are doing with said API. You can setup an API to perform purely CRUD operations or you can make your API a lot smarter and say have it serve up actual HTML to be rendered on the client (which is sort of what MVC does) or you can take it a step further and turn it into a Hypermedia service that will define the view as well as the state of your system. The front end is then tasked with simply rendering what is provided by your API.

Comment: I think the approach I'm going to take (for now), is to have the API just do CRUD and let JavaScript/jQuery take care of calling on the API and displaying the returned data (if there is any). If I understand things correctly, I could make my API calls from the server if I wanted and that is just a design choice. Correct? Additionally, am I correct in thinking that my MVC application may be the only app that is consuming the API and using the API(method?) is just a way of separating concerns?

Comment: I would upvote you as well...but I have a bad rep still.