# Redirect from APIController action to other MVC controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a web api controller that has an register action:

```
public class MyProjApiController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Register()
        {
            return  RedirectToAction("Register", "AccountController"); //??
        }
    }
```

And I am trying to redirect to another action in MVC Controller `public class AccountController : Controller` that has  `public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegVM model)` but my Register action in `MyProjApiController` has `IHttpActionResult` return type and register in AccountController has `Task<ActionResult>` type - how to call it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are mixing two concepts here. Your API controller should have endpoints which will be called from some client and you should be returning some data back in a format which client can read, XML or JSON. You should not be doing a redirect to another MVC controller.

What you should be doing is return some data which has the path to the MVC action controller which the client can use.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Register()
{
   //DO something as you want 
    var newUrl = this.Url.Link("Default", new { Controller = "Account", 
                                                Action = "Register" });
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
                             new {Success = true, RedirectUrl = newUrl});
}
```

This will return you a response like this to the caller with 200 OK response status code

```
{
   "Success" : true,
   "RedirectUrl" : "yoursite.com/Account/Register"    
}
```

The client should read this and do the necessary things. For example, If you are calling this API from your js code, You can simply use window.location.href to redirect the user to the new page.

For example ,

```
$.post("PathToYourApiEndpoint",function(res){
  if(res.Success)
  {
    window.location.href = res.RedirectUrl;
  }
});
```

Again,I am not sure why you are calling the API first and the redirecting the user to the MVC controller action. Whatever logic you are doing in the Web api action method, you might be able to do in your MVC controller and thus avoid your API call.

Comment: so, something comes in post (RegisterModelClass as JSON), I verify it, and send back to client another JSON with redirect URL - correct?

Comment: Depends on where you are calling it from. If you are calling the Web api end point to verify something before letting the user go to the register page, You might be calling this end point from your js code. So get the response, check the value and redirect the user to the new page using `window.location.href`.

Comment: I will try to call it via android device

Comment: @curiousity Then why are you trying to redirect to the MVC controller. Your register should be an API endpoint

Answer (score 0):

If you mean from the API help file. I wanted to disable except for local.

```
if (!Request.IsLocal)
{
  Response.Redirect("/home");
}
```