# How to call Controller from APIController Class Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
public class ResitController : ApiController
{
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Resit(string invoiceNo)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home","");

    }

}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("");
        }
}
```

I need to RedirectToAction to render a View from this controller method above,
but it cannot resolve "RedirectToAction".

Please help by suggesting alternatives to it.

The final output should render a view from the controller.

Comment: Please clarify what _"but it cannot resolve RedirectToAction"_ means.

Comment: the name "RedirectToAction" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You can probably use the `var newUrl` part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548484/3181933) as a basis for doing it.