# ASP.NET API Controller POST/Redirect/Get

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, redirect, post, asp.net-web-api

I would like to use the P/R/G design with this API, using AngularJS on the client side.  Here is my API method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateRaw(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
       //do stuff...

        var res = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);

        var authority = request.RequestUri.Authority;
        var uri = string.Concat(authority, "/api/DataApi/GetRaw");

        res.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);

        res.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        return res;
    }
```

I have another method in this controller (`DataApiController`) which is called `GetRaw()`.  Basically I want the client to issue a POST, call this method, then get redirected to the GET method.  Here is my JS code:

```
//get the data and build the js rep
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/DataApi/UpdateRaw',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            },
            data: {
                test: "test"
            }
        }).then(function (result) {
            console.log("RAW--------------");
            console.log(result.data);

            // do stuff...

        }, function () { console.log("DIDN'T WORK"); });
```

When I issue the POST, however, my browser console says "`The request was redirected to a URL ('localhost:25498/api/DataApi/GetRaw') which has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests.`"  I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action) answer, but that had the same result.

I found another website somewhere which suggested adding the line

`res.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

but that does not seem to work either.

I am new to ASP.NET and Web Dev in general, so any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: how do you do the post, in the browserm with fiddler, how?

Comment: The JavaScript I put up there sends the POST.

Comment: This pattern isn't necessary if you're use AJAX calls in a single page application.   In these apps there generally isn't a form resubmission.