# how to use response.redirect in webapi+asp.net?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to redirect to another `.aspx` page from `WebAPI`. I have used this code but it is not working:

```
string url = "http://localhost:61884/UserList.aspx";
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(url);
return Redirect(uri).ToString();
```

Comment: Have you tested it with Fiddler or some other sniffer that the request is not actually redirected to the target file ? because this can be a client side issue which is not related to the server.

Comment: You don't or your description of the problem is not accurate. Web API is meant to retrieve data or persist data, basically a way to interact with the server from the client without having to do the traditional form post or page request. The caller needs to execute the redirect once the results from the call to the Web API are retrieved. The Web API should not any type of redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
string fullyQualifiedUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
response.Headers.Location = new Uri(fullyQualifiedUrl);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. (*or your description of the problem is not accurate*)

Web API is meant to retrieve data or persist data, it is a way to interact with the server from the client without having to do the traditional form post or page request calls. The caller (javascript based on your question tag angularJs) needs to execute the redirect once the results from the call to the Web API are retrieved.

- This is good SOC (separation of concerns), the business logic in the Web API should not care about routes (angularjs) / web pages.
- Even if you wanted to the Web API, because of how its called, can't redirect the client.

Summary: The Web API code itself should not any type of redirecting of the client. The client should handle this.

---

Sample call to web api and redirect from angular code:

```
$http({
    url: "/api/SomeWebApiUrl",
    data: {},
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json" },
    responseType: "json"
}).then(function (response) {
    if(response.data.somethingToCheck === someConditionThatWarrentsRedirect)
        $window.location.href = "~/someOtherUrl/";
});
```

Answer (score -1):

[Redirect from asp.net web api post action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action)

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
   // ... do the job

   // now redirect
   var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
   response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.abcmvc.com");
   return response;
}
```