# Use Redirect in Web Api Controller (HTTP 302 Found)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-302

For some reason I am having lots of trouble trying to find out how to redirect (`HTTP 302 Found`) to an absolute URL from within a controller.

I have tried this:

```
this.Redirect("/assets/images/avatars/profile.jpg");
```

But I get an exception thrown

> Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Every other answer I see on here doesn't seem to be available to me. I am using `Web API` and `MVC 5`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With `Redirect`, you need to send a **valid** `URI`. In your case, if you want to return only the `relative URI`, you **must** tell it to `URI class`:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Redirect(new Uri("/assets/images/avatars/profile.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core 2.1, and probably lower version of .NET Core, you cannot pass in a Uri. So you have to create the Uri and call the .ToString() method.

Like so.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult Get()
 {
        Uri url = new Uri("../Path/To/URI", UriKind.Relative);
        return Redirect(url.ToString());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some non sense shortcoming from my viewpoint. The .Net Framework Web Api Redirect method does not support getting an uri path string as a location.

So you have to do as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40389536/1178314) tells.

But rather than doing that every time you have to redirect, it is better to fix that API:

```cs
/// <inheritdoc />
protected override RedirectResult Redirect(string location)
{
    // The original version just crash on location not supplying the server name,
    // unless who asked it to please consider the possibility you do not wish to tell
    // it every time you have a redirect to "self" to do.
    return base.Redirect(new Uri(location, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

I am putting this in my base controller, and so can forget about this shortcoming.