# RedirectToRoute doesn't go to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using **RedirectToRoute** in my API controller to redirect to MVC controller. I was unable to find a good solution other than this:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Cv", new { action = "Cv/OpenCv" });
```

Previously I tried this below, but it didn't work.

```
return RedirectToRoute("Cv", new { controller="Cv", action = "OpenCv" });
```

Comment: I also have a routename called Cv. :) . RedirectToAction is not available in API controller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Redirect in Web Api Controller (HTTP 302 Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386554/use-redirect-in-web-api-controller-http-302-found)

Comment: I saw this solution :) . Is it better than the one I have used in the first block? thanks for the effort man!

Comment: Api and MVC Controllers use different Routes. RedirectToRoute in Api controller returns "System.Web.Http.Results.RedirectToRouteResult" but RedirectToRoute in Mvc Controller returns "System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult". I think you can use just "Redirect" method in this case. Just wondered why do you need this?

Comment: You can try to create an Mvc UrlHelper (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_UrlHelper_RouteUrl_System_String_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_) instance and use a RouteUrl method to build an Url from route parameters and then call Redirect method.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. will you please give it as an answer so that i can reward you for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Api and MVC Controllers use different Routes. RedirectToRoute in Api controller returns "System.Web.Http.Results.RedirectToRouteResult" but RedirectToRoute in Mvc Controller returns "System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult". I think you can use just "Redirect" method in this case.

You can try to create an Mvc UrlHelper instance and use a [RouteUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_UrlHelper_RouteUrl_System_String_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_) method to build an Url from route parameters and then call Redirect method.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect from API controller to MVC controller by the help of below code.
Please find below code for the above question.

```
public IHttpActionResult Index()
{
    var newUrl = this.Url.Link("Default", new
    {
        Controller = "Account",
        Action = "Register"
    });
    return Redirect(new Uri(newUrl.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

or follow the direct call from API Controller

```
public IHttpActionResult Index()
{
   return Redirect(new Uri("/Account/Register", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

Please use the above code and let me know