# How to call one controller from another controller with Header Request in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

How to call one controller from another controller with Header Request in C#? Can somebody tell me.This is the code of ctrlABC and i want to call ctrlABCD method with the header request because ctrlABCD method is working from directly via URL also so i dont want to edit it

```
public string GetDetailAPI(ModelABC obj)
        {
            var response = "";
            string ControllerName = "CtrlABCD/GetDetail/";
                string BaseAddress = "http://192.168.3.21/WFXWebAPI/";
                string pageParams = "ID|" + obj.QueueTaskKey + "~";
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("pageParams", pageParams);
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
                    response = client.GetStringAsync("api/" + ControllerName).Result.ToString();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
```

This is the code of ctrlABCD

```
public DataSet GetDetail()
        {
            obj = new ClsABCD();
            string pageParams="";
            var re = Request;
            var headers = re.Headers;
            if (headers.Contains("pageParams"))
                pageParams = headers.GetValues("pageParams").FirstOrDefault();
            return obj.GetDetail(pageParams);
        }
```

Comment: call it with a HttpWebRequest, just like you'd do from a consumer

Comment: @mjwills yes. They are and Code is running from CtrlABC.cs and i want to call method of CtrlABCD.cs with the header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect from asp.net web api post action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the overloads method `RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName);`

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController");
```

**and**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Name","Index", "MyController", null, null)
```