# How redirect post page to post page by use C# Webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

Now I have page A submit (post method) to page B 
I want to create api at  middle between  page A and B  for  track  some value to DB from page A

page A submit  form---> new c# web api --->   page B

How I can ?  pls  suggest  me .

I try follow this link  But  not  work
[How to make HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request/4015346#4015346)

Comment: are you using jquery or anyother frontend javascript framework for ajax post? can you show your code how you doing?

Comment: Check below links - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action)

Comment: Please show us your code so we can better understand your scenario.

Comment: My original  code of page A is below



<form action="pageB"  method="post">
<input ../>
<input ../>
....
</form>

I want change action="pageB"  to action="net core web api page "  then 
api redirect to  pageB

I want create api as  middlepage , don't create front page (html  JS) as middlepage   Can I do ?

Comment: `page A submit form---> new c# web api ---> page B` You can try to make your API controller action return [Redirect("url")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirect?view=aspnetcore-3.1), like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8ft0.png).

Comment: How post variable from page A via Redirect(url) to page B