# Redirect from asp.net web api post action doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js

As a new comer to ASP.Net looking for workaround on, redirecting to another URL at the end of the HttpResponseMessage POST api.

In reference to [Redirect from asp.net web api post action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action) I tried same procedure to redirect. Api returns response to caller but no redirect is happening. The Api call response goes to fail callback on javascript side.

Any suggestion on solving this is greatly appreciated.

Tried calling Post API from Javascript. Always throws error with CORS.

// C# API

```
[HttpPost] 
[Route("SignInTest")] 
public HttpResponseMessage Post(SignInModel signInModel)
 {
    HttpResponseMessage response = null; 
    EntityResponse<UserAuthenticationDTO> userAuthenticationDTOResponse =         
       _authenticationService.Validate(signInModel.Login, signInModel.Password); 
    if (userAuthenticationDTOResponse.IsSuccess) 
    {
       var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
       response.Headers.Location = new Uri("https://sample.com"); // to url that I have to redirect
       return response; // expected https://sample.com to load 
    } 
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,     ErrorCode.AccountVerificationEmailIsNotVerified); 
    return response;
 }

// Javascript Caller
dataContext.singleSignOn.SignInTest(self.validatedObservable).done(function (data)
{
   console.log("data", data);
}).fail(function (error) 
{
   console.log("done with error", error); // Always throws error with CORS for https://sample.com to load .
  
});
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] question to focus on a single problem - clearly, you've already researched on CORS issues so hopefully that is not what you looking for here. Are you looking for explanations how to check if HTTP call returned 301/302 status instead of 200? Are you looking for explanation why JavaScript ajax calls don't redirect the page (probably not as you want C# answer)? Please [edit] the question with [MRE] (that makes sense rather than code currently in the question with orphaned `new Uri("https://sample.com");`) as well as with clarification of what exactly you need help with.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Basically I am trying to call post API that which has to redirect to given redirectUrl. Post edited.