# .net web API: How to retrieve routes/route templates from controller class method which represents an API operation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to build an call back URL (kindof web hook) and therefore I'm required to get the route path of a given class method which represents an API operation.

Let's say, my controller looks like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    public MyController(ILogger<ServicesController> logger)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost("operationVerb1/{what}")]
    public string DoSomething(string what)
    {
        IEnumerable<RouteEntryTypeOrSo> operationRoutes;
        
        if (what == "looks like for verb2 ...")
        {
            operationRoutes = ?? // get routes for MyController.DoSomething2
        }
        else if (what == "looks like something else ...")
        {
            operationRoutes = ?? // get routes for MyController.DoSomething3
        }

        // pick an adequate route of the list
        var callbackRoute = operationRoutes.FirstOrDefault(x => whatevercondition);

        // create a URL
        var callbackUrl = new Uri("https://" + Request.Host.ToUriComponent() + callbackRoute.EndpointOrWhateverProp);

        // call back URL whould then look like "https://blablabla.com/api/operationVerb2"

        return $"Ok, we're doing something, but in half an hour you must call ...{callbackUrl}";
    }

    [HttpGet("operationVerb2")]
    public string DoSomething2()
    {
        // do whatever
    }

    [HttpGet("operationVerb3")]
    public string DoSomething3()
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

How to achieve?

[Edit]: The target operation is not neccessarily on the same controller which should generate the URL. The example above is just a very simple example.

I'm using .net 6.0.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate - check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324711/redirect-from-asp-net-web-api-post-action

Comment: Hi @AmoghSarpotdar - checked that, but nope - it's not about redirection, it's about knowoing routes ...

Comment: Do you mean you want to get current web api's route information? Could you please tell me which rule you want to follow?  Just controller first rule or second rule or else?

Comment: What you are trying to do is done through routing attributes. The {what} route parameter you are supplying is taking execution to DoSomething method which accepts another parameter (string what). I am treating these two 'what's distinct values. If that is the case then second 'what' - the string parameter should not be used for routing. Its your data that should be processed. Its the first 'what' (attribute on method) that can be used to determine routing in first place.

Comment: You could have two DoSomething implementation with individual routing attributes set to operationVerb1/what1 and operationVerb1/what2 as distinct routing attributes. The logic that you are trying to implement (abstracting away the decision of whether to call what1 or what2), does not belong inside your controller. It should be done by the calling class. If that is not the case, i.e. you think that logic belongs to controller being called, then you dont need those endpoints in first place. You could use simple private methods.

Comment: @BrandoZhang: Exactly, acutally I like to have a mapping from the controller method to it's possible routes. I will then pick one appropiate entry in that list, in case there are more routings for the same controller method.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar: Routings don't need necessarily attributes, in circumstances the route can also be retrieved by the controller method's name. Same counts for the controller itself. Don't concentrate on the 'what' condition, this is only example, the condition's data can also be retrieved from some other place than the input parameter ... the goal is to have a controller-method to api-route(s) mapping.

Comment: @user1470240 - 'Routings don't need to be attributes, can be retrieved by the controller method'- I agree on this. However what I find difficult to understand is the business requirement where controller needs to make a decision on what route to choose. Typically web API are used for standard CRUD operations with some variance in search / insert / update criteria. I cant visualise a requirement where controller needs to make a logical decision on which API route to call. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design#organize-the-api-design-around-resources.

Comment: @user1470240 - can you please explain the business case where you need APIs such that it needs to make a logical decision on what other public API it needs to call? I am curious to understand why this decision cannot be shifted over to calling side, so that API is free from having any predefined logic that results in tight coupling. What I suspect is your problem is not technical, its probably a design issue.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar: Sorry, you probably missunderstood the goal: I dont want to choose a route, I want to generate dynamically an URL for an API endpoint, so it can be called from outside later - think it kind of a Webhook. Actually you can also forget about the what-condition ....

Comment: are you still looking for ans or you have already solved it ?

Comment: @Nitz: Yes, still looking for proper solution here - currently I drive with some ugly hardcoded workaround ...

Comment: @user1470240: I have provided a solution below. see if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to achieve something similar using `IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider`

see if this fits your need.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider _apiDescriptionsProvider;
    public MyController(ILogger<ServicesController> logger,
           IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider apiDescriptionsProvider)
    {
       apiDescriptionsProvider = apiDescriptionsProvider;
    }

    [HttpPost("operationVerb1/{what}")]
    public string DoSomething(string what)
    {
       var applicableApiDescriptions = 
    _apiDescriptionsProvider.ApiDescriptionGroups.Items
           .SelectMany(group => group.Items);

        IEnumerable<ApiDescription> operationRoutes;   
    
        if (what == "looks like for verb2 ...")
        {
           operationRoutes = applicableApiDescriptions.Where(a => a.GroupName == "operationVerb2"); // get routes for MyController.DoSomething2
        }
        else if (what == "looks like something else ...")
        {
          operationRoutes = applicableApiDescriptions.Where(a => a.GroupName == "operationVerb3"); // get routes for MyController.DoSomething3
        }

    // pick an adequate route of the list
    var callbackRoute = operationRoutes.FirstOrDefault(x => whatevercondition);

    // create a URL
    var callbackUrl = new Uri("https://" + Request.Host.ToUriComponent() + "/"+ callbackRoute.RelativePath);

    // call back URL whould then look like "https://blablabla.com/api/operationVerb2"

    return $"Ok, we're doing something, but in half an hour you must call ...{callbackUrl}";
   }

   [HttpGet("operationVerb2")]
   [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "operationVerb2")]
   public string DoSomething2()
   {
    // do whatever
   }

  [HttpGet("operationVerb3")]
  [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "operationVerb3")]
  public string DoSomething3()
  {
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty close, just in my case the target URL to build is in another controller, and the apiDescriptionsProvider gives me the operations of the current controller (which makes sense). How can I retrieve So ... IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider for a specific controller?

Comment: you should mention that in your question that the target url are in separate controllers.

Comment: did you tried with different controller. because it will work for that also. `IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider` gives also the APIs for all the controllers not just the current one.

Comment: You're right, I've changed the article text to hint about 'sister-controller' possiblity. I also found out, why in my case, I cannot see the operations from the 'sitser-controller'. Because this controller has a convention that he is not visible in the API Explorer (ActionModel.ApiExplorer.IsVisible = false). That's because this controller acts rather as internal call back and threfore should not be promoted outside. When IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider does depend on API Explorer - what other possibility I have? In either case - thanks for the current effort!